# ubuntu on nokia lumia 2520

Tags: tablet, nokia

I have a Nokia Lumia 2520 with win rt..... I like the device but I can't go with the os, is very very limited, I want to install Ubuntu but I don't find any forum with specific information with this tablet, can it be installed on it? What version you recommend?

Comment: @markkirby: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more?  **;-)**  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: @Fabby done....

Answer (score 1):

This is a Windows RT (ARM) tablet, there is no Ubuntu for this type of device, it is very restricted, you can't even have Android, Windows RT only.

Related questions on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31539935/is-it-possible-to-install-android-5-0-lollipop-on-nokia-lumia-2520) and [Ubuintu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196076)

Comment: :-) :-) :-)  ;-)